adminer on docker compose: How to secure connection?
I am using adminer over nginx-proxy. Relevant docker-compose lines:
version: "3"

services:
  nginx:
    image: "jc21/nginx-proxy-manager:latest"
    hostname: websin.space
    container_name: npm
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "81:81"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - ./data:/data
      - ./letsencrypt:/etc/letsencrypt

  db:
    image: mysql:latest
    volumes:
      - ./db:/var/lib/mysql
      - ./init:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: doNotTellPasswordsOnStackOverflow
      MYSQL_DATABASE: so
      MYSQL_USER: so
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: doNotTellPasswordsOnStackOverflow

  adminer:
    image: adminer
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 9080:8080
    environment:
      ADMINER_DEFAULT_SERVER: db
    depends_on:
      - db    

Now, when I deploy it, I can connect to the database over
http://websin.space:9080 as I specified port in the yaml file.
However, I would like to make this connection secure. How can I do that?

TL;DR: Let Docker assign the port for the first time and then use it
Replace
ports:
      - 9080:8080

with
ports:
      - 8080

Keep only 8080 port in the ports section. Then run docker ps
Some port will be assigned by default by docker compose
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                             COMMAND                  CREATED          STATUS         PORTS 
3d766a78be19   adminer                           "entrypoint.sh php -…"   10 seconds ago   Up 9 seconds   0.0.0.0:32768->8080/tcp, :::32768->8080/tcp

Then in nginx proxy make port forwarding to port 32768 and let it create ssl certificate
Later on, replace again the ports section to
ports:
 - 32768:808

And the SSL will be preserved even after restart.
There may be better solution than this, still open to suggestions
